# Mongoose & Bluebird - typical callbacks within promises?

Tags: javascript, mongoose, bluebird

Is there a better way to resolve the outer callback without explicitly invoking it from within the then()?  IE next(false) vs next(true).  My current implementation doesn't "feel" correct.  Or perhaps it is, and this is just the nature of writing it.

```js
AccountSchema
  .path('email')
  .validate(function (value, next) {
    this.constructor.findOneAsync({email: value})
      .then(function (user) {
        if (user) {
          next(false);
        }

        next(true);
      });
  },
  'The specified email address is already in use.');
```

Comment: You could have that inner function just call `next(!user);`. Or were you thinking of something else?

Comment: Well I was looking at the nodeify() construct within bluebird, but I'm not sure if it would apply here.